# NSURL errors with caret ^ in string

Tags: xcode, swift

Attempting to get data on the S&P500 (symbol: ^GSPC) from Yahoo Finance. In playgrounds and scripts, the presence of a caret (^) in the string passed to NSURL errors with **"Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, sub code=0x0)"**. Xcode 6b6 and b7.

Works fine with other ticker symbols (AAPL, MSFT, etc).

Any suggestions for how to get this working?

```
let symbols:String = "^GSPC"
let financeURL:String = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=\(symbols)&f=sl1c6p2"

var financeNSURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: financeURL) // ERROR (see above)
let tickerNSData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: financeNSURL)

var output:NSString = NSString(data:tickerNSData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's crashing because Swift (at least in Xcode6-Beta7) doesn't support returning `nil` from an object initializer. From the release notes:

> Swift does not support object initializers that fail by returning
>   null. (16480364)
>
> Workaround: If there is a factory method, use it instead. Otherwise,
>   capture the result in an optional. For example:
>
> `let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: "not a url")`

So, to avoid a crash, declare your `financeNSURL` as `NSURL?` (as in the example from the docs above), or use [`NSURL.URLWithString()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:) instead of `init(string:)`.

However, the root of the problem is that you're not encoding your URL parameters correctly.

If you call `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(...)` on `symbols` it works:

```
let symbols:String = "^GSPC".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
let financeURL:String = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=\(symbols)&f=sl1c6p2"

let financeNSURL: NSURL? = NSURL(string: financeURL)
if let url = financeNSURL {
    let tickerNSData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

    var output:NSString = NSString(data:tickerNSData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

Output:

```
"^GSPC",1999.83,"-2.45","-0.12%"
```

Comment: According the documentation, when the string is not properly encoded, then in Swift there seems no other way than to crash. I do agree though, that this is not a desired behavior from a developers perspective.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yep, true. I edited the answer to explain the crash and provided the current workaround.

Comment: It explains it very well, now. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - works great. (There's no need for a workaround, at least to avoid a crash, since there is no crash – it just errors out in Playground or a script. I assume it crashes on compile?)

Comment: @Skonesam the crash would be at runtime if the URL was invalid in some way. When the Playgound shows you `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`, that would be a runtime crash.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a `NSURL`with init method `NSURLWithString:` the parameter *URLString* must be a *properly encoded* URL string. Your's is not. So, what is this a "properly encoded URL string"?

The corresponding official documentation gives a few more hints where to read:

"*URLString*: The URL string with which to initialize the `NSURL` object. This URL string must conform to URL format as described in [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396), and must not be `nil`. This method parses `URLString` according to [RFCs 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) and [1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808)."
(links are mine).

So basically, you need to separately encode each URL component from your source string component using the correct variant of the percent encoding algorithm. Then, compose all encoded string components to the final URL string.

This can be tedious and is certainly error prone. Thus, since iOS 8 there is `NSURLComponents` ([see docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html)) which can aid you in this task.