# Certain characters make moveItemAtURL:toURL:error: crash. how do I avoid them?

Tags: cocoa, swift

First, I'm using Swift. Second this line works fine in my code:

```
let didIt = fileManager.moveItemAtURL(originalFilePath, toURL: newFilePath, error: nil)
```

...as long as there are no special characters in the newFilePath. if the newFilePath has a dollar sign or an ampersand ($, & ) in it, the line fails.  My issue is that the newFilePath comes from a text field in a window where the user can type any old thing.  How do I escape special characters, or encode them so they will pass the test and be included in the new filename?

thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: can you show the declarations of `originalFilePath` and `newFilePath`?   It sounds like that's where your problem is.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646971/nsurl-errors-with-caret-in-string/25649058).

Comment: thanks for the tip, Mike, but when I use NSUTF8StringEncoding, my paths all work with no crashes, but the filename has %20 everywhere there should be a space...

Comment: newFilePath = newFilePath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(txtResultName.stringValue!.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that the newFilePath comes from a text field in a window where the user can type any old thing.

Right there is your problem. Why are you not using an `NSSavePanel` for letting the user select a name under which to save a file?

If you insist on taking input from a text field, the docs for `-URLByAppendingPathComponent:` specifically say that the path component string should be "in its original form (**not URL encoded**)" (emphasis mine).

How did you originally create `newFilePath`, before appending the path component? For example, you should have used one of the methods with "[fF]ileURL" in the name.